# How to filter an array based on matching values (header & content)?

Tags: reactjs

Array to be filtered:

```
[
     {
       categoryName: "Chinese food",
       tabs: [
           {
             header:
                "Chicken Rice",
             content:
                "Hainanese chicken rice is a dish of poached chicken and seasoned rice"
           },
{
             header:
                "Dim sum",
             content:
                "large range of small Chinese dishes that are traditionally enjoyed in restaurants"
           }
       ]
     },
     {
       categoryName: "Italian food",
       tabs: [
           {
             header:
                "Pizza",
             content:
                "Dish of Italian origin consisting of a usually round"
           }
       ]
     }
```

Output when matching keyword in header is "Chicken Rice". It will filter the tabs in every CategoryName with similar header and content. The output is as below:

```
[
  {
       categoryName: "Chinese food",
       tabs: [
           {
             header:
                "Chicken Rice",
             content:
                "Hainanese chicken rice is a dish of poached chicken 
               and seasoned rice"
           }
         ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const items = [{
    categoryName: "Chinese food",
    tabs: [{
        header: "Chicken Rice",
        content: "Hainanese chicken rice is a dish of poached chicken and seasoned rice"
      },
      {
        header: "Dim sum",
        content: "large range of small Chinese dishes that are traditionally enjoyed in restaurants"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    categoryName: "Italian food",
    tabs: [{
      header: "Pizza",
      content: "Dish of Italian origin consisting of a usually round"
    }]
  },
]

var value = 'Chicken Rice'

const finalResult = items.filter(({
  tabs
}) => tabs.some(({
  header
}) => header === value)).map(ele => {
  let result = Object.assign({}, ele, {
    'tabs': ele.tabs.filter(
      tabs => tabs.header === value
    )
  })
  return result;
});

console.log(finalResult)
```